# Replacing expression within data.table

Tags: r, regex, data.table

I'm running the following code below to retrieve a data set, which unfortunately uses "." instead of NA to represent missing data. After much wrangling and searching SO and other fora, I still cannot make the code replace all instances of "." with NA so I can convert the columns to numeric and go on with my life. I'm pretty sure the problem is between the screen and the chair, so I don't see a need to post sessionInfo, but please let me know otherwise. Help in solving this would be greatly appreciated. The first four columns are integers setting out the date and the unique ID, so I would only need to correct the other columns. Thanks in advance you all!

```
library(data.table)
google_mobility_data <- data.table(read.csv("https://github.com/OpportunityInsights/EconomicTracker/raw/main/data/Google Mobility - State - Daily.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
# The following line is the one where I can't make it work properly.
google_mobility_data[, .SD := as.numeric(sub("^\\.$", NA, .SD)), .SDcols = -c(1:4)]
```

Comment: you can use fread to input your data, which accepts na.strings argument to declare that . is NA

Comment: Thank you @MichaelChirico. It would be a perfect solution, but... I'm getting error in curl::curl_download, HTTP error 400. This in my two machines (both Windows 10, one runs R 3.6.1 and the other one runs 4.0.2.

Comment: perhaps use `readLines` to load the data as a character vector. Then `gsub` to change `,.,` to `,NA,` and `,.$` to `,NA$`.  (With appropriate escaping for the `.`) Then read that modified character vector using `fread`.

Comment: if you're getting the Http error with fread, but not read.csv, could you please file a bug report?

Comment: Yes, will do. Thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4659

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your data and changed the last entry on the first row to "." to test NA in the final column.

Use `readLines` to read a character vector.

Use `gsub` to change `.` to `NA`.

Use `fread` to read as a data.table.

```
    library(data.table)
    gmd <- readLines("Google Mobility - State - Daily.csv")
    gmd[c(2,3120)]
    
#    [1] "2020,2,24,1,.00286,-.00714,.0557,.06,.0129,.00857,."
#    [2] "2020,4,25,10,-.384,-.191,.,-.479,-.441,.179,-.213"  
    
    gmd <- gsub(",\\.,",",NA,",gmd)
    gmd <- gsub(",\\.$",",NA",gmd)
    gmd[c(2,3120)]
    
#    [1] "2020,2,24,1,.00286,-.00714,.0557,.06,.0129,.00857,NA"
#    [2] "2020,4,25,10,-.384,-.191,NA,-.479,-.441,.179,-.213"  
    
    google_mobility_data <- fread(text=gmd)
    google_mobility_data[c(1,3119)]
    
#   year month day statefips gps_retail_and_recreation gps_grocery_and_pharmacy gps_parks gps_transit_stations gps_workplaces gps_residential gps_away_from_home
#1: 2020     2  24         1                   0.00286                 -0.00714    0.0557                0.060         0.0129         0.00857                 NA
#2: 2020     4  25        10                  -0.38400                 -0.19100        NA               -0.479        -0.4410         0.17900             -0.213
    
    summary(google_mobility_data)
```

EDIT: You mentioned using `na.strings` with `fread` didn't work for you, so I suggested the above approach.

However, at least with the data file downloaded as I did, this worked in one line - as suggested by @MichaelChirico:

```
google_mobility_data <- fread("Google Mobility - State - Daily.csv",na.strings=".")
google_mobility_data[c(1,3119)]
   year month day statefips gps_retail_and_recreation gps_grocery_and_pharmacy gps_parks gps_transit_stations gps_workplaces gps_residential gps_away_from_home
#1: 2020     2  24         1                   0.00286                 -0.00714    0.0557                0.060         0.0129         0.00857                 NA
#2: 2020     4  25        10                  -0.38400                 -0.19100        NA               -0.479        -0.4410         0.17900             -0.213
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. When I downloaded the csv files, indeed the fread approach from @MichaelChirico went smoothly. However, I still couldn't download it straight from the web, which is what ideally my code would be doing (since this date is updated constantly and it's supposed to be an automatically-updated notebook.) However, even the offline fread reading is already an amazing improvement! In any case, thanks to you DaveTurek, Michael and others who viewed and thought about it. Much appreciated!